# Доступ к переменной

Tags: ооп, php

Ребята, помогите пажалуйста, не могу получить доступ к переменной $id описанной в методе getContent(). Доступ пытаюсь получить в методе getComm().

protected function getContent() {

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=cp1251;dbname=blog", "root", ""); 
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    if($_GET['id_descr']) {
    $id = $_GET['id_descr'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pop WHERE id = '$id'");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if( $row!="" ) {

    $sm_read = file("templates/text.html");
    $sm_read = implode("",$sm_read);

    echo "<div id='content'>";
    printf($sm_read,$row['img'],$row['url'],$row['title'],$row['price'],$row['article'],$row['text']);
    //--------вывод комментариев
    self::getComm();
    echo "</div>";
        }

    protected function getComm() {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=cp1251;dbname=blog", "root", ""); 
    $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM comm WHERE descript='$id' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();

    $sm_read_comm = file("templates/comm.html");
    $sm_read_comm = implode("",$sm_read_comm);
    if( $row!="" ) {
        while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
            printf($sm_read_comm,$row['author'],$row['date_b'],$row['text']);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Объявите переменную id в классе за пределами функций.

```
class foo() {
    private $id;
    protected function getContent(){ 
        $this->id = $_GET['id_descr']; 
    }
    protected function getComm(){ 
        echo $this->id; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все настолько просто))) Я недавно начал изучать ООП, но походу еще не осознал основных положений, будем работать в этом направлении.